# Usar campos personalizados de usuarios en el listado de usuarios en WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

He instalado un plugin en wordpress que permite insertar formularios de registro para los usuarios con campos personalizados (en mi caso, "Compañía" y "CIF")

La inserción de datos se realiza correctamente, pero quiero, además, mostrarlos en la sección de usuarios tal y como en la captura de pantalla que adjunto:

[image: listado de usuarios]

Para ello, estoy usando las siguientes funciones que añado al archivo `functions.php`:

```
function theme_add_user_company_column( $columns ) {

     $columns['company'] = __( 'Compañía', 'theme' );
     return $columns;
 } 
 add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'theme_add_user_company_column' );
```

Con este he creado la columna que se visualiza en Usuarios

```
function theme_show_user_company_data( $value, $column_name, $user_id ) {

     if( 'company' == $column_name ) {

         return get_user_meta($user_id , 'company', true );
     } // end if

 } // end theme_show_user_zip_code_data
 add_action( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'theme_show_user_company_data', 10, 3 );
```

Con este otro he llenado la columna con los registros que he introducido en el formulario.

El problema que tengo es que al intentar lo mismo para CIF me dejan de aparecer los datos de compañia. Solo puedo mostrar un tipo de dato cada vez y no se por que puede ser.

Comment: ¿Estas usando ACF (Advanced Custom Fields)? Es de los mejores plugins para este tipo de cosas, te da tambien varias funciones para luego poder obtener fácilmente esos datos en cualquier parte de Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

Falta el código que utilizas para crear la columna del CIF. Asumiendo que es una copia exacta del que usas para la columna de la compañía, creo que el problema es que estás añadiendo dos veces la acción `manage_users_custom_column`, con lo cual la segunda "sobre-escribe" la primera...

Pienso que necesitarías algo como:

```
function theme_show_user_custom_columns_data( $value, $column_name, $user_id ) {

  if ('company' == $column_name) {
    return get_user_meta($user_id, 'company', true );

  } elseif ('cif' == $column_name) {
    return get_user_meta($user_id, 'cif', true );
  }
}
add_action( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'theme_show_user_custom_columns_data', 10, 3 );
```

De todas formas, hace mucho que no uso WordPress y podría estar totalmente equivocado :)

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con el siguiente código:

```
// Crea las columnas
function column_register_user( $column ) {
    $column['compania'] = 'compania';
    $column['cif'] = 'cif';
    return $column;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'column_register_user' );


// LLena las columnas con los campos extra
function column_user_table_row( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'compania' :
            return get_user_meta( 'compania', $user_id );
            break;
        case 'cif' :
            return get_user_meta( 'cif', $user_id );
            break;
        default:
    }
    return $val;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'column_user_table_row', 10, 3 );
```